# Why does my query yield a different result after the first time?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

When I query firebase with this code

```
results = []
const result = this.dbRef.database.list(`/answers/${questionId}`)
               .do((array) => { console.log( JSON.stringify(array));})
               .map((array) => array.reduce((acc, element) => 
                                             acc + element.$value, 0)
               )
               .subscribe(sum => this.results.push(sum));
```

the array that is emitted by the observable is for example

```
[{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges1"},{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges2"},{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges3"}]
```

and the value 9 is pushed to `results` as expected.

But when this code is executed again, the array returned is empty and then filled with objects one-by-another, so in the end `results` holds `9,0,3,6,9`.

What is going on here, why does `this.dbRef.database.list(/answers/${questionId})` yield something different after the first time?

I tried to call unsubscribe *after* `sum` should have been pushed to the array, but then nothing happened at all, so `results` stayed empty.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some related issues with this behaviour.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/574, https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/662